# How to configure winforms controls so they don't overlap each other

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I have made a user control, which contains 7 controls(labels, dateTimePickers and Combobox), which are placed in a row. It looks like this:[image]

Now i need to resize my usercontrol and i wanted to specify minimum width for each element(child control) and i also configured anchors, but when i resize the form, controls overlap each other. How can i configure this properly, or, maybe, i need to use some container for this?

I'll be gratefull for any help!

Comment: Are you using the controls inside a container, or are they all anchored to the main form?

Answer (score 1):

I'd place them all inside one of the WinForms layout containers, such as the [`TableLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4yc3e8c%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) or [`FlowLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) *(tutorials [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2006/04/05/winforms-autolayout-basics-tablelayoutpanel.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb798028.aspx)*).

You'll have to play around to see if they'll work for your situation, but they generally take care of keeping controls separated and prevent unintended overlapping.

Comment: Grant, i tried to use FlowLayoutPanel, but i couldn't configur it properly, when i resized it, my button (which is on the right side) just dissapered. In your link(tutorial about FlowLayoutPanel) i haven't found how can i figure it out

Comment: i want all my child controls to resize to their minimum size. For example, i set width of 7 controls to 200px and minimum width to 100px, so that this control will need 1400px width, but when i'll resize controls will just get smaller, so that i could resize the control to 700px (100*7). Hope, you understand me

Comment: I even know how to make it in wpf, but my project uses winforms. So u don't have any suggestion how to make? Or i'll have to write my own OnResize logic?

Answer (score 0):

try to use split container then dock your controls inside the split container